# Singleton class that show a toast in different activities using resources efficiently

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-activity, android-toast

I have a singleton class (let's call it: **SingleWorker**) that it's used in multiple activities. Depending on the case it shows a toast or a progress dialog if a task is being done. I have 2 ways in my mind on how to do this:

1) creating a separate method in the singleton - SingleWorker, that will get the context of the activity before the toast/progress is shown

2) in the extended Application singleton, I will store, every time I enter a new activity (and on its onResume) its instance, that i will then use that in the SingleWorker singleton.

Which one is the better choice (I guess the first one), can I do it better? I tried to find an efficient answer by myself, but I need a direction or a tip. Any idea, suggestion, advice or link is gratefully received. Thanks for reading !

Comment: Does the `SingleWorker` really need to store the context?

Comment: I guess, because i really need to show a dialog during the execution of the tasks or a toast (both of the require the context to be shown :( ) if the task fails, and this process repeats itself in multiple of activities in my project. But if you can give me an ideea of how i can avoid storing the context and still show them I would be really happy :D

Answer (score 0):

I was using the second approach for a long time and decided to move to the first one after a few problens. 
Storing the context in the BaseActivity is better when you need the it outside the context (a background thread for example) To show toast's or dialog's you can just pass it to the method in singleton class ( approach 1), you will be free of memory leaks and will not have to worry about giving the contextStored a new value in onResume() and onDestroy() methods.

Here is an example of a method to show a dialog:

```
 public static void showAcceptDialog(String message, final Context contex, View.OnClickListener onClickYes, View.OnClickListener onClickNo) {
    dialog = new Dialog(contex);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_of_your_dialog);
    TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.generic_accept_message);
    //Seta o titulo do dialogo
    tv.setText(message);
    Button btNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.generic_dialog_no);
    if (onClickNo != null) {
        btNo.setOnClickListener(onClickNo);
    } else{
        btNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    Button btYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.generic_dialog_yes);
    if(onClickYes != null){
        // dialog.dismiss();
        btYes.setOnClickListener(onClickYes);
    }
    else {
        btYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, I think the same way at the moment. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`Toast`s are not bound to a specific `Activity` in terms of their visibility. 
That's one of the reasons why they where somewhat 'deprecated' (not officially, that's just my interpretation of Google's design guidelines and their own apps) in favor of the [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) which is bound to a specific `View`.

I see no advantage in using an `activity context` instead of the `application context` to create a `Toast`.

Vice versa, when letting your `Singleton` hold a reference to `activity context`s, you might very easily create a memory leak by holding on to an already destroyed `Activity`. 
You could just pass in the `Activity` as a method parameter, but that might not be so convenient (e.g. calling that method from a class other than `Activity`).

Long story short: I would suggest to let your `SingleWorker` have a reference to the `application context` to create the `Toast`.

Comment: Interesting ideea, I'll try it tomorrow at work, thanks!